# How to enable read/write for windows partitions?

Tags: partitioning, 64-bit

With 11.04 I could read and write my partitions that was created in Windows however after upgrading to 11.10 somehow I can only read those partitions. How do I enable this ability in 11.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking for this package
`ntfs-3g`.

This will allows you to read/write ntfs partitions

Comment: Ok will do that and report

Comment: thanks for this answer you don't know how much I appreciate it

Comment: had the same problem! Since when is is not default anymore? Why the hell??

Answer (score 1):

The main problem for this is that your window machine is not shutdown properly, and it will not until you turn off the "Fast StartUp" option in window(which is by default turn on (selected) in window. Here are steps to do this:-

- Control panel
- Power Option
- System Settings
- Down you will see the option of Shutdown Settings
- Save changes

Hurray you are all set to go. Restart your machine and you are able to write the file(Open the folder and create file. Go here for more info about change StartUp settings (https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html)